# Cannot run genhtml in dart project

Tags: dart, dependencies, code-coverage, dart-pub, lcov

I'm a newbie, I wanna learn Dart language.So basically I wanna display my coverage report. Follow in this https://pub.dev/packages/test_coverage. When I using genhtml command it not working

```
'genhtml' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And in my pubspec.yaml

```
name: fordart
description: A sample command-line application.
# version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'

#dependencies:
#  path: ^1.6.0

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.8.0
  test: ^1.6.0
  test_coverage: ^0.4.1
dependencies:
  lcov: ^*
```

What I missing and can all you guys advice more coverage tools supported Dart language.I searched in Google there are many coverage tools like CodeCOV, Coverall, Codacy,... but it's so hard to set up in Dart projects beacause Dart language is not a popular language and the coverage tools maybe not supported for it .If you guys know how to set up please contact me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now doesn't seem like repositories with only Dart work with Codacy

Answer (score 0):

The `lcov` package puts down the `genhtml` command.

If you're on `OSX`:

```sh
❯ brew install lcov
Warning: lcov 1.15 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.15, run:
  brew reinstall lcov

❯ command -v lcov
/opt/homebrew/bin/lcov

❯ command -v genhtml
/opt/homebrew/bin/genhtml
```

If you're on other Linux, including Amazon Linux 2:

```sh
❯ yum install lcov

❯ command -v genhtml
/usr/bin/genhtml

❯ command -v lcov   
/usr/bin/lcov
```

If you get a message the package cannot be found, you might need to enable the repo, especially true on Amazon Linux 2:

```sh
❯ yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

See: [Add repositories on an Amazon Linux instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html)